# Push notification not working in samsung galaxy s5

Tags: android, push-notification, samsung-mobile

> I integrate amazon for push notification it's working fine in all device except Samsung galaxy s5. I already check from app info that show notification is checked. i cant figure out what happen.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, this happened with me once. Notifications are coming in all devices except one. After some investigation, I found out that when Push Notification Id changes in my phone and I failed to update on server. And when I send push notification, as Amazon have old push notification Id, it detects push notification did not receive on the client and hence, blocks this Id.

So, my advice is check push notification id is changed and you are updating the new id on the server.